# Html.ActionLink doesn’t render # properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When using Html.ActionLink passing a string containing the # char renders it like it is but if you UrlEncode it renders as %2523.

I believe it's a bug. MVC Beta Release.

Is it really a bug?

http://example.com/test# is rendered as

[http://examplee.com/test%2523](http://example.com/test%2523) instead of

http://examplee.com/test%2523